# Python to Capture stats of games being played by members of my Discord server

Tags: python, discord, statistics, bots

I'm interested in creating a bot that captures all of the games members of my server are playing and gives me the stats so I can see which games members of my server are most interested in. Basically, when you see a users status says something like "...playing Minecraft" or "...streaming Roblox", etc. I want to capture that. My ultimate goal is to be able to enter a command like:

```
/getgamestats
```

And have it return something like:

```
Roblox 38
Minecraft 27
GTA 22
```

I found this, which seems to be a way to set a specific status, but would like to learn how to get the status.
[SET playing status](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/discord+bot+playing+status+python)

I'm guessing I'd also need some kind of database included to store the stats.

Answer (score 3):

You can access a user's current activity with [discord.Member.activity](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.activity). Below is an example of accessing member activity. Be aware that the [default Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.default) does not include [presences](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.presences), including the activity of members on your server.

```
import time
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild: discord.Guild = client.get_guild(GUILD_ID_HERE)
    while(True):
        for member in guild.members:
            print(member.activity)
            # access member.activity to do stuff
        time.sleep(5)

client.run(BOT_TOKEN_HERE)
```

Also be aware that in order to access member activity, you will need to enable [privileged gateway intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahqz1.png) on the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

In order to store user statistics long-term, you will need to look for your own storage solution (such as a database), as Discord does not provide past user activity.